# Is social media affecting the creativity of students?

Tags: education, social-media

I have been observing my small sister for about a year now that there has been a huge decline in her studies and academic results and this all has happened soon after we got an Android device common for the home and she has started using it to chat with her friends and use social media platforms.

My question is - Is social media making her smarter and the only bad thing is the number of hours of usage or should I stop her from using it since it's useless and just a waste of time?

Comment: I would be careful to outright "stop her from using it". Forbidden fruit is the most tantalizing, after all. I wonder if there is a way to artificially speed the progression of realizing it's a waste of time. You'd have to make her time more valuable to her.

Comment: This site is for questions about postgraduate study and/or teaching at universities. I think that this question as it is currently worded is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally useless and a waste of time. There is a reason why Australian states are banning the use of personal electronic devices in public K-12 education.

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate on said reason.